# My code is not printing the required result

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int N;
    cin>>N;         
    int count=0;
    vector<int>v1(N);
    vector<int>v2(N);
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        int t1,t2;
        cin>>t1>>t2;
        v1.push_back(t1);
        v2.push_back(t2);
    }
```

### I think only this piece of code has the problem

---

I want to increment and print the value of **count** but its not working.Is there any problem while dividing two **integers** and assigning it into **float type var** or something else.

```
    for(int i=0;i<v1.size();i++)   
    { 
        float x=(v1[i]/v2[i]);                  
        float y=(v1[i]/v2[i]);      
        if(x>=1.6 && y<=1.7)
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    cout<<count;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "its not working" is not a proper problem description. please give example input and expected and actual output

Comment: oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow (SO)! Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Note that `3 / 5 = 0`.

Comment: As a side note see [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721)